# Use rails_admin for Sorting fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sorting, rails-admin

Is there a way to sort fields in rails admin. Not in the way, as sort for viewing but sort in the model?

For better understanding:

You got a list of items

- Arthur Dent [Sort ID: 1]
- Ford Prefect [Sort ID: 2]
- Tricia Marie McMillan [Sort ID: 3]

Now you rearrange them in the rails_admin view:

- Tricia Marie McMillan [Sort ID: 1]
- Arthur Dent [Sort ID: 2]
- Ford Prefect [Sort ID: 3]

And the Sort ID's are automatically switched.

I hope you understand what I mean, it's little hard to describe

Comment: Did my answer help your problem? Did you find a solution?

Comment: Write your model definition. What is 'SortID'?

Comment: There is information in the docs about adding orderable fields https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Associations-basics

Comment: Any way of having some functionality in the list for reordering items directly? (I'm thinking of up/down buttons that interchange the positions based on the order field)

Comment: I'm using acts as list and there exists solution for sorting list in activeadmin but i couldn't find any for railsadmin. How did you solve this problem. Can you suggest some solution for rails_admin?

Comment: Same problem here, this worked like a charm: [rails_admin_nestable](https://github.com/dalpo/rails_admin_nestable) (title is misleading but it does exactly what you asked for)

Answer (score 3):

By default, rows are sorted by id in reverse order, You can change default behaviour with the two methods: sort_by and sort_reverse

```
RailsAdmin.config do |config|
  config.model Player do
    list do
      sort_by :name
      field :name do
        sort_reverse false
      end
    end
  end
end
```

You can find more information here: https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/List

Comment: PascalTurbo wants to re-order the list through rails_admin not change the default order i think